# Using ISO-8859-1 on jQuery UI button title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, character-encoding

I'm changing an existing page that is encoded with ISO-8859-1 and I can't change its encoding to UTF-8.

I'm using jQuery UI Dialog to send some informations to user.

Everything is fine, except by the fact of some buttons have accented chars as bellow:

```
buttons: [
{
    text: "SIM!",
    click: function() { //'yes' button clicked }
}, {
    text:'NÃO',
    click: function() { //'no' button clicked }
}
]
```

When I display the dialog, the "NÃO" button becomes "N&Atilde;O" but the browser ignores the html entity and displays N&Atilde;O.

I also tried to put N&Atilde;O instead of NÃO, but didn't work.

Is there any way to properly display the accented Ã on a jQuery UI button?

---

### UPDATE

After fight this problem all morning I saw what was going on... The CMS was changing only the javascript texts to HTML entities (It's the worst CMS I ever saw). I solved the problem creating a hidden div with the text I wished to put on button and used it, instead of just place an string, as bellow:

**before:**

```
buttons: [
{
    text: "SIM!",
    click: function() { //'yes' button clicked }
}, {
    text:'NÃO',
    click: function() { //'no' button clicked }
}
]
```

**after:**

```
    buttons: [
    {
           text: "SIM!",
       click: function() { //'yes' button clicked }
    }, {
       text:$("#badcms").html(),
       click: function() { //'no' button clicked }
    }
    ]
</script>
(...)
<div id="badcms" style="display:none">NÃO</div>
```

Comment: I can't actually see the difference between NÃO and NÃO

Comment: Can you please provide a screen shot? Encoding issues are notoriously hard to communicate across layers that deal with encoding themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I have to edit the question. The &amp;Atilde; was converted to Ã on both cases.

Comment: @Alnitak I edited the question to use inline code blocks to reveal the original markup.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `label` property instead of `text`? `text` is for enabling/disabling the label and in your case it will always be enabled since non-empty string literals are truthy. You could be simply seeing the labels that were in the original markup (possibly what's inside `<button>` elements).

Comment: Sorry, @AtesGoral, I also edited the question.

Comment: I'd recommend switching to a Unicode encoding (UTF-8 is the most popular and is backwards compatible with ASCII).  I know you say you can't, but its only going to lead to problems like this (Charset Hell)

Comment: @GordonM I agree, but the it's an old page and it gets information in ISO-8859-1. Can't change the encoding.

Comment: After fight this problem all morning I saw what was going on... The CMS was changing the code to & Atilde;. I can't understand why & Atilde; wasn't being displayed correctly by browser.

Comment: @javsmo What about my comment about using `text` versus `label`? You should also double check that it does what you intend it to do. The usage in your code excerpt is not correct.

Comment: label didn't worked for me... text did.

Comment: @javsmo Please define "worked". It could be doing something that's not really what you think it's doing. The `text` property is used for enabling/disabling the button label. The `label` property is used for overriding the button label that's in the original markup. By setting `text` to a string, you're merely saying, "show the label", without changing what the label is. Or I'm totally missing something here...

Comment: @AtesGoral When I used "Label" the text didn't appear on button. It appeared when I used "text". On jQuery UI Documentation I found an example like this: `$( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
] });` [http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Comment: @javsmo I can't see the example you're quoting from at that URL. I simply don't see a `text: "Ok"` anywhere. Also, you tried lowercase "label", right?

Comment: @AtesGoral On that page, click on "Options" and after on "Buttons (Array)". Yes, I tried with "label" in lowercase.

Comment: @javsmo Ah... Got it now. For some reason I was thinking you were using `.button()`, which has different option names :/ Sorry for pestering you about the "text" property...

Comment: @javsmo So you finally have a solution to your problem? That's great. You can actually post an answer below and accept your own answer as the right answer for closure.

Comment: @AtesGoral As it wasn't an specific jQuery problem (the ugly CMS was the villain) I thought it was better to edit the question. Do you think it's better to put that update inside an answer?

Comment: @javsmo I think you can do both simultaneously so that the question & answer reflect the root of the problem and people searching for the solution to a similar problem can easily find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested on comments, I'm answering my own question.

---

After fight this problem during one entire morning, I saw what was going on... The CMS was changing only the javascript texts to HTML entities (It's the worst CMS I ever saw). I solved the problem creating a hidden div with the text I wished to put on button and used it, instead of just place an string, as bellow:

**before:**

```
buttons: [
{
    text: "SIM!",
    click: function() { //'yes' button clicked }
}, {
    text:'NÃO',
    click: function() { //'no' button clicked }
}
]
```

**after:**

```
    buttons: [
    {
           text: "SIM!",
       click: function() { //'yes' button clicked }
    }, {
       text:$("#badcms").html(),
       click: function() { //'no' button clicked }
    }
    ]
</script>
(...)
<div id="badcms" style="display:none">NÃO</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert (transcode) the file from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. A good editor can do this (e.g., Notepad++). Then just make sure that encoding is properly declared (an essential part of moving to UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

Why not encode the entity?

```
N&#195;O
```

Comment: Or even better (from a maintenance perspective): `&Atilde;`

Answer (score 0):

As `.text` escapes entities in any format, you could set the initial text to `text:'NAO'` then fetch the button and update its html;

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonset').children('button:contains(NAO)').html("N&Atilde;O");
```

Although I suspect any subsequent manipulation of the buttons would reset this.

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery-UI Dialog has a solution for this.  Instead of using the 'text' attribute, use the 'html' attribute like so:

```
buttons: [
    {
        html: "SIM!",
        click: function() { //'yes' button clicked }
    }, {
        html:'N&Atilde;O',
        click: function() { //'no' button clicked }
    }
]
```